# Excel - how to QOTIENT and MOD numbers under 1?

Tags: excel

Hi i would like to solve this problem i want MOD 2 fields and also QUOTIENT 
it can do 0,4/0,2  or 0,4/0,4 but 0,2/0,2 no idk why =\

```
J5 = =MOD(J4;J6)
K5 = =MOD(J5;K6)
L5 = =MOD(K5;L6)   = PROBLEM IS HERE it cant do MOD 0,2 and 0,2 it should return 0
M5 = =MOD(L5;M6)
N5 = =MOD(M5;N6)
L6 = 0,5€ ...

L7 = =QUOTIENT(K5;L6)
M7 = =QUOTIENT(L5;M6) = same problem it should return 1 cause 0,2/0,2
```

Excel Screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what might be happening is a rounding error due to the fact that computers calculate using base2. Try `=INT(L5/M6)` instead of the `QUOTIENT` function.

Comment: Sorry. There was a mistake in my function. I just fixed it.

Comment: @peter works when i give INT(L5/M6) but 2 blocks up i have MOD(L5;M6) where i cant use INT =\ 
there is MS Online [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Amc9ZIPJXACTtRtGHwydQNzH9ijR)

Comment: it fixs only 1st problem and 2nd no still where is MOD(L5;M6) is wrong and if this is wrong whole Excel list is wrong =\

Comment: Pay let me look at the mod. One moment.

Comment: u can use my Own Excel file its MS Online File : [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Amc9ZIPJXACTtRtGHwydQNzH9ijR)

i will see whot is changing

Comment: `=MOD(L5*100;M6*100)/100`

Comment: Did this fix it for you?

Comment: no works same value "0,20" and plus now i got warning in Left corner

Comment: I tried it in your excel sheet and it works. That should go into cell M5.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code I gave you into cell M5?

Comment: nop i just typed it by my self, thanks a lot, idk why this problems happends but THX :)

Comment: I just edited your file and I think you should be able to see the edit on your end, but I don't know.

Comment: Did you see that change?

Comment: yes i see it , also instant changed in my PC too :), Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. The problem was that in excel, the mod function doesn't like to play with fractions. So what I did was multiply the values by 100 and then divided the result by 100.

Comment: Sorry I was getting confused by the question. It's 4am here and I was looking at it on my phone.